# How to extract individual columns of data from a record in sqlite?

Tags: javascript, sqlite, gnome-shell

I am writing an extension for the gnome-shell. The javascript extension spawns a sql query and captures the output on standard output.

The result of the query produces records with 2 columns. I can't seem to extract each column of a record individually because the delimiter used, in this case a '|', can possibly occur in either of the columns which are strings themselves.

How do I go about achieving the same? I am new to this type of real programming(i.e, databases, gnome, javascript). My previous programming experiences have been limited to implementing algorithms taught in the course/textbooks.

I recognise that this problem would dissappear if there was a javascript/gnome interface to sqlite3 like the [c/c++ interface](http://www.sqlite.org/quickstart.html). I could then extract each column in a record with ease.

Googling in search of such an interface did not help me. I searched for "javascript interface for sqlite" and "gnome interface for sqlite".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the sqlite3 command-line utility, you can use the `.format` command to specify other output formats. `.separator` and `.headers` might also come in handy. Run sqlite3 and enter `.help` for more details.

Comment: Thanks. Though I do not use the command line utility, your answer reminded me of 'man sqlite3'. The -line option seems best suited for my purposes.